# Getting unsupported_operation_exception in elasticsearch when I use wildcard (*)

Tags: php, elasticsearch, yii2, kibana, query-string

Below code was working in the elasticsearch 7.8 but it's throwing error after upgrade the elasticsearch server to 8.5. please have a look and let me know the solution.

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must":{ 
         "query_string": { 
             "fields":["id","title","description"], 
             "query":"*"
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

"type":"unsupported_operation_exception"

"reason":"all shards failed"

"status":400

Comment: Provide the error message

Comment: edited.. can you please check?

Comment: I cant reproduze the error in elastic v8.4

Comment: should I share the mapping array?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's only coming on v8.5 as I've upgraded from 7.8 to 8.5

Comment: did you try to reproduce in a test index? Maybe you have some analyzer that is causing the error.

Comment: yes.. i created new test index, where i got the same issue

Comment: I'll try to change the mapping array tomorrow as i can't access the code atm :).. please keep following this issue.. I'll inform you the status tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250532/discussion-between-rabbitbr-and-purvi-singh).

Comment: Try removing field 'id' from "fields":["id","title","description"] and check if it is working.

Comment: The error cause was highlighter type.. I was using plain type and now I have changed it to unified.. its working well.

Comment: Please add an answer where you describe the solution.